# unknown URI scheme while opening bin file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.5, I try to open .bin file with Word2Vec representations  downloaded from source http://ling.go.mail.ru/static/models/ruscorpora_russe.model.bin.gz

Doing it with the following code

```
import gensim.models 
Word2Vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('D://ruscorpora.model.bin', binary=True)
```

I get an error.

**NotImplementedError: unknown URI scheme 'd' in 'D://ruscorpora.model.bin'**

How can I tackle this problem?

Comment: What if you change '//' to '\\' ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the path argument expects an URI. URI Schemes are these things; `file://` or `smtp://`. But a drive letter is not an URI Scheme.

So there are two options:

1. You heard that you have to write `\\` instead of `\` in Python for pathes which is right. But you do not have to write `//` instead of `/` since `/` does not have to be escaped; write: `D:/file.bin` or `D:\\file.bin`
2. The argument should be an URI: write something like: `file://D/file.bin` like you would do in a browser.